# ngbDropdownToggle in child component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap and angular9

I have some different type of dropdown in my app, and one of them is inside a table. I wanted to customise the toggle, so I made a component from it

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <app-button-cell
    [iconUrl]="'assets/svg/more-horiz.svg'"
    [dropdownId]="'dropdownBasic1'"
  ></app-button-cell>
  // dropdownMenu
</div>
```

and the button cll looks like this

```
   <div
    [id]="dropdownId"
    ngbDropdownToggle
    class="button-cell d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
  >
    <svg-icon [src]="iconUrl"></svg-icon>
  </div>
```

It works nice, but when I click, only the FIRST time I have.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at NgbDropdown._positionMenu

Is there a simple fix for this